# Required tooltip displayed when close modal in FireFox

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Got a strange issue, I am developing an angularJS app that is to use Firefox only but I have an issue with the tooltip on a modal if the user clicks the `Close` button.

When the modal opens there is a dropdown list which is blank by default and is also required. The modal also has a `Submit` button and `Close` button.  The `Submit` button is disabled until all mandatory fields are completed and the `Close` button is always enabled.

If you click the `Close` button without selecting an option (which is a valid action) the modal closes as expected but the required tooltip is displayed.

Does anyone know of a fix for this issue?

Comment: Could you add some html please ? Some Code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the sample code is not exist, based on your question I tried a solution with the "Submit" and "Close" buttons.

Whatever the button you clicks, it fires the submit's function. So you need to block the execution by using `$event.preventDefault();`

**Sample HTML**

```
<form name="form" novalidate ng-submit="saveModal()">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">
            <span>Submit</span>
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="closeModal($event)">
            <span>Close</span>
        </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Sample Controller**

```
$scope.closeModal= function ($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    // Close modal related codes here
};

$scope.saveModal = function() {
    // I assume that the required tooltip related codes are available 
    // inside the submit's function
};
```